# Aggregate calculation query on single SQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

In my database I have a table, `payers_payments`, consisting of some foreign keys (`payer_id`, `payment_id`) and some pivot fields (`amount`, `pays`).

```
| id | payer_id | payment_id | amount | pays |
|----|----------|------------|--------|------|
| 1  | 1        | 1          | 20     | 0    |
| 2  | 2        | 1          | 23     | 1    |
| 4  | 1        | 2          | 14     | 1    |
| 5  | 2        | 2          | 17     | 1    |
| 6  | 1        | 3          | 10     | 1    |
| 7  | 2        | 3          | 0      | 0    |
```

Each row represents a contribution a `payer` made towards a `payment`. The `pays` field specifies whether that `payer` should be included in the payment.

The total cost of a `payment` is the sum of `amount` for a given `payment_id`. So if I wanted to see how much payment 2 cost I would run:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) AS sumOfPayment 
  FROM payers_payments  
 WHERE payment_id=2;
```

Likewise the total amount a given `payer` (say, payer 1) has contributed is:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) AS sumOfPayment 
  FROM payers_payments 
 WHERE payer_id=1;
```

Now, what I want to do is use the concept of **fair share**. Fair share is the total cost of the payment divided by the number of `payers` who have `pay=1` for that payment. The simplest way I can express this is with a sub-query:

```
SELECT SUM(payers_payments.amount) / (SELECT count(*) 
                                        FROM payers_payments 
                                       WHERE pays 
                                             AND payers_payments.payment_id = 3
                                             ) AS FairShare
  FROM payers_payments
 WHERE payment_id=3
GROUP BY 
       payers_payments.payment_id;
```

For a given `payer` and `payment` their fair share is defined as:

```
SELECT IF(pays, FairShare, 0) as payerFairShare 
  FROM payers_payments 
 WHERE payer_id = 1 
       AND payment_id=3; --FairShare is the query as above
```

My question is that I want a query to get the total **fair share** for each `payer` based on the fair share of each payment and whether or not they are included in the payment. (If `pays=false` then their fair share is 0)

Based on the above data this is the kind of result I'm after for the 2 payers:

```
| payer_id | total_paid | fair_share |
|----------|------------|------------|
| 1        | 44         | 25.5       |
| 2        | 40         | 58.5       |
```

Is there a way to achieve this in a single query or must I do some looping of result sets?
I am agnostic on RDMS but something MySQL-like is good.

Comment: Should be doable with a subquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start by writing a query that works what a single share of a payment is.  That is, per `payment_id`, the sum of all the amounts, divided by the number of people it needs to pay.  That result can then be joined back to the original data.

```
SELECT
  payers_payments.payer_id,
  SUM(payers_payments.amount                      )   AS total_paid,
  SUM(payers_payments.pays * payments.single_share)   AS fair_share
FROM
  payers_payments
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT
    payment_id,
    SUM(amount) / SUM(pays)   AS single_share
  FROM
    payers_payments
  GROUP BY
    payment_id
)
  AS payments
    ON  payers_payments.payment_id = payments.payment_id
GROUP BY
   payers_payments.payer_id
```

It will be of benefit to have indexes on both `(payment_id)` and `(payer_id)`.

It will be of benefit to have the `amount` field in a DECIMAL data-type, though you need to consider what you want to do with rounding.  *(A total payment of 10.00 needs to be divided three ways, 3.33 each and then what do you want to happen to the spare 0.01?)*

Comment: Wow, nice job. So the query makes a non-existant table `payments` to hold the single shares? I already have a `payments` table so I guess it makes sense to call it something else but it works! Amount is stored as decimal with >2 decimal places so as far as rounding is concerned amounts are rounded to 2 dp in views so there will be slight error which I don't mind about at the moment. Been trying to get this for weeks so appreciate the help.

Comment: @harryg - It doesn't actually create a table, it's just a sub-query.  Something similar to a view that only exists for the duration of the query.  But choosing names that don't conflict is often good practice to aid maintenance.

Comment: @harryg - Be careful of holding amounts to more than 2 decimal places in order to "get around" the rounding errors.  It can cause money to "disappear" slowly over time.  One option in the case of `10.00 / 3` is to give two people `3.33` and one person `3.34`.  another is to create a "fund" that gathers the spare `0.01` to give away in some way.  But it's generally considered very poor practice to allow people to have `3.333333` *(because to can't have 0.003333 of a currency)* while also allowing the `0.000001`'s to "vanish from the accounts".

Comment: Fair points, thanks for your advice. I will implement this query in my app (need to try and replicate the query in Laravel/Eloquent). Once I have my head around things I will work on the rounding. As the data is calculated dynamically (I.e. results are not stored) I'm assuming rounding can work both ways and will even out over time.

Comment: @harryg - That's a dangerous assumption for which many accountants will have a field day with you.  But depending on your context that may not matter to you, I have no idea.  That said, I agree that getting it working is pretty important as a first step ;)  Good luck.

Comment: One extra thing: how would I limit my query to only select records for a certain user_id, assuming there is a joined `payers` table (`payers_payments.payer_id = payers.id`) that contains a `user_id` foreign key? I'm having trouble adding the join to your query

Comment: Could you open a new question, and give an example of the data, the query you tried, and your problems?  Add a comment to me and I'll have a look later today, only have access via my phone right now :)

Comment: Question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22520366/1606323. I feel it is due to my nested joins not being liked by SQLite as mentioned in an answer so will check it later.